# Get string outside val?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a question about the written piece of code below.

I have created a val called TEMP in the batteryBroadcastReceiver now I want to request that data TEMP outside the batteryBroadcastReceiver but that doesn't work.

Does anyone have an explanation for me how I can display TEMP outside the batteryBroadcastReceiver

```
val test = temp

private val batteryBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver(){

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if(intent?.action == "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"){

            val temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0)
            // set the text view
            tvBatteryTemp?.post{
                tvBatteryTemp?.text = "${temp}" + "°C"
                startService(this@ForegroundService,"${temp}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a global variable and access the value of temp using that.

Code:

```
val temp: Int = 0

public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Example Code of how the temp value can be accessed now and would be dynamic
    val testBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    testBtn.setOnClickListener { 
        Toast.makeText(this,"Your temp value is $temp",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


private val batteryBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver(){

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if(intent?.action == "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"){

            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0)
            // set the text view
            tvBatteryTemp?.post{
                tvBatteryTemp?.text = "${temp}" + "°C"
                startService(this@ForegroundService,"${temp}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped you out. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Happy to help, always!